# Concept based Template member functions overloads

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, c++20

An example of how we would overload template member functions of a template class in the absence of concepts is shown in [this snippet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LTFXW82vKJDN1HhM).

Now roughly attempting to write something similar using concepts:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo{
    Foo(T elem): elem_(elem) {}
    template <typename U = T>  requires Integral<U>
    int get() {
        return -1;
    }
    template <typename U = T>  requires Bool<U>
    int get() {
        return 0;
    }
    T elem_;
};
```

Two ways to organize this would be:
1. Keeping declaration and definition together: This works as expected. [Code Snippet](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77255d2bfa04602e)
2. Separating declaration and definition: Fails to compile([Code Snippet](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93462057a3bbada1))

**Given the above, I had two questions:**
1. The reason `template <typename T> template <typename U=T> member_fn...` was originally needed due to SFINAE. Is there no way to avoid this with Concepts to simplify the code further?
2. How can I correctly separate the declaration and definition?

Comment: If you keep the declarations (instead of removing them) it will fail because a call to ambiguous function. Note that compiler support for C++20 features is still experimental.

Comment: Using `Integral<T>` to mean _just_ `int` is a bit surprising

Comment: @Barry just meant for it to be a minimal running example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the constraint of a template must be the same in the declaration and the definition (see [[temp.over.link]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#6)). Otherwise the compiler could not be able to deduce to which declaration refers a definition.

So this code will compile:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo{

  Foo(T elem): elem_(elem) {}

  template <typename U = T>  requires Integral<U>
  int get() ;

  template <typename U = T>  requires Bool<U>
  int get() ;

  T elem_;
  };

template<class T>
template<class U> requires Integral<U> 
int Foo<T>::get() {
  return -1;
  }
template<class T>
template<class U> requires Bool<U>
int Foo<T>::get()  {
  return 0;
  }
```

Then the concept check delaying trick using defaulted template argument is not required because it is possible to associate constraint to a function in its [trailing require-clause](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#4):

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo{

  Foo(T elem): elem_(elem) {}


  int get() requires Integral<T>;

  int get() requires Bool<T>;

  T elem_;
  };

template<class T>
int Foo<T>::get() requires Integral<T> {
  return -1;
  }

template<class T>
int Foo<T>::get() requires Bool<T> {
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, when trying this along with explicit specializations(like the wandbox example) - it hits an ODR-like error: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f527e6119ba8684. My guess is this is because concepts are not involved in name mangling leading to such double defs - but then how can I apply explicit specializations commonly used to segregate declaration/impl for templates?

Comment: @tangy This is a bug, the trailing require clause belong to the signature of the function: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.defs#defns.signature.member. The first technique exposed in this answer should work.

Comment: as in a bug with the gcc concepts TS implementation?

Comment: @tangy Neither conforming to the concept TS nor to C++ 20. I suppose changing C++ name mangling would have been too heavy for an implementation intended to experiment c++ concepts.